# How to sign flutter's apps

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, flutter

I'm starting to work with flutter and I would like to know how to sign apps to publish in stores. I work with MacOS and IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: The signing process is not documented. See the tracking issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6825 .

Comment: I'ts documented [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#adding-a-launcher-icon)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have already solved it. The technical issue can be solved by writing the command inside the project´s directory:

```
$ flutter build apk --release --keystore /Users/user/Desktop/Sign/my-key-release.keystore --keystore-password=p@$$w0rd --keystore-key-alias=name-alias
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the newest version of the flutter command. It always complains that --keystore doesn't exist

Comment: Here's an issue I created for this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39764

Comment: @CiriousJoker - Were you able to find a solution for this? I require this for bitbucket pipeline

Comment: Nope. We ended up just hardcoding the path into our build.gradle file. Good luck!